# Makefile : "make" fails but "make -d" and "make -n + hand execution" works

Tags: debugging, module, makefile, fortran

A simple Makefile has a strange behavior... it is killing me.
To summarize :

_"make" produces an error

_"make -n" + execution by hand works (-n display the commands that would be executed by make, I then execute each command one after another on my terminal)

_"make -d" works (-d just displays debug informations!)

I try to compile a Fortran code with some modules

This is my makefile (there are just seven .f90 source files) :

```
F90 = gfortran  # Fortran Compiler 
FLAGS=          # Compiler flags
LDFLAGS =       #Linker flags

OBJ_DIR_NAME := obj
SRC_DIR_NAME := src
BIN_DIR_NAME := bin

PWD :=  $(shell pwd)
OBJ_DIR := $(PWD)/$(OBJ_DIR_NAME)
SRC_DIR := $(PWD)/$(SRC_DIR_NAME)
BIN_DIR := $(PWD)/$(BIN_DIR_NAME)

# List of source files 
SRC := $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.f90)

# List of object files :
NAME := $(basename $(notdir $(SRC)))
OBJ := $(addprefix $(OBJ_DIR)/, $(addsuffix .o, $(NAME)))

# To make the executable
all: make_directory $(OBJ)
    $(F90) -o $(BIN_DIR)/$(EXEC) $(OBJ) $(LDFLAGS) 

# Rule to make directories
make_directory: dirobj bin

# Create all .o and .mod from the .f90 found
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.f90
    $(F90) -J$(OBJ_DIR) -I$(OBJ_DIR) -c $< -o $@ $(FLAGS)

.PHONY: dirobj bin

# Create the directory $(OBJ_DIR) if needed :
ifeq ($(strip $( $(wildcard $(OBJ_DIR)) ) ), )
dirobj: 
    mkdir -p $(OBJ_DIR)
else
dirobj: 
endif

# Create the directory $(BIN_DIR) if needed :
ifeq ($(strip $( $(wildcard $(BIN_DIR)) ) ), )
bin: 
    mkdir -p $(BIN_DIR)
else
bin: 
endif 

.PHONY: clean purge 

# Clean remove all .o and .mod
clean:
    rm -rf $(OBJ_DIR)
# Clean + remove executable
purge: clean
    rm -rf $(BIN_DIR) $(OBJ_DIR) OUTPUT_FILES
```

These are the commands made by "make" :

```
gfortran -J./obj -I./obj -c src/define_derivative_matrix.f90 -o obj/define_derivative_matrix.o 
gfortran -J./obj -I./obj -c src/gaussm3.f90 -o obj/gaussm3.o 
gfortran -J./obj -I./obj -c src/gll_library.f90 -o obj/gll_library.o 
gfortran -J./obj -I./obj -c src/lagrange_poly.f90 -o obj/lagrange_poly.o
gfortran -J./obj -I./obj -c src/modules.f90 -o obj/modules.o 
gfortran -J./obj -I./obj -c src/source_time_function.f90 -o obj/source_time_function.o
gfortran -J./obj -I./obj -c src/specfem1d.f90 -o obj/specfem1d.o
gfortran -o bin/xspecfem1d obj/*.o
```

It produces the following error message :

```
  use grid
    1
Fatal Error: Can't open module file 'grid.mod' for reading at (1): No such file or directory
```

The error message comes from :

```
gfortran -J./obj -I./obj -c src/specfem1d.f90 -o obj/specfem1d.o
```

This needs obj/grid.mod created by:

```
gfortran -J./obj -I./obj -c src/modules.f90 -o obj/modules.o
```

But this file has been properly created! (It is in obj/ at the end of the "make")
And if I run each command one after another by hand everything work perfectly! Even "make -d" works... But not "make"...

Have you ever seen such a problem? It is as if make would not wait for the end of the previous commands to execute the others. Thank you for your help!

Cheers

Edit: I have solved this problem by adding a small "sleep" before

```
gfortran -J./obj -I./obj -c src/modules.f90 -o obj/modules.o
```

But I should not have to do that in a perfect world...

Comment: Hello, I have messages like :  use grid
      1
Fatal Error: Can't open module file 'grid.mod' for reading at (1): No such file or directory. But this module grid.mod exist at the end of the "make" command. It is as if

Comment: I have a theory. When you run Make, does it produce `grid.mod`? And if so, *where* does Make put it?

Comment: Is my question clear now?